# Erorr when trying to create a multiple-choice in React-Native

Tags: react-native, multiple-choice

I am trying to create a simple multiple choice like that

'

```
use strict';

import React, {
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import MultipleChoice from 'react-native-multiple-choice'

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MultipleChoice
                    options={[
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit',
                        'Lorem ipsum',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor'
                        ]}
                    selectedOptions={['Lorem ipsum']}
                    maxSelectedOptions={2}
                    onSelection={(option)=>alert(option + ' was selected!')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 60,
        margin: 20
    },
});

export default Home
```

But it gives me this erorr when I try to run it : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.default.PropTypes.array')

Somebody has any idea what the problem could be ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-multiple-choice/issues/20

Comment: Thank you, I have checked it, but nobody seems to find a solution.

Comment: yes, I think there is some issue in package. Package owner needs to fix.

Comment: I have changed the package now using 'rn-multiple-choice', but now it gives me an error:'TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function'. Any idea with this one?

Comment: try this one:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-select